# How to overlay a menubar by a logo - How to get it?

Tags: navbar

I would like to overlay a navbar by a logo (See picture below). Unfortunately I lack any approach how to realize this for html/css website. Do you have tips, an approach or vllt. even correct codes for me? I would be very very grateful!

I tried everything - without any result.

I'm sorry I am relative new on HTML and CSS

Would be great to got functional CSS ans HTML Codes to solve my problem.